# how to view stats on snowflake?

Tags: sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a way to visualize the stats of a table in Snowflake.

The long step is to pull a meaningful sample of the data with python and apply Pandas, but it is somewhat inefficient and unsafe to pull the data out of snowflake.

Snowflake's new interface shows these stats graphically and I would like to know if there is a way to obtain this data with query or by consulting metadata.

[image]

I need something like Pandas-profiling but without a external server. maybe snowflake store metadata/statistic  about its colums. numeric, categoric
https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling

thank you for your advices.

Comment: The highlight in your screenshot isn't statistics about the data in the table, but merely about the query result. For example, if you look at `type`, it simply tells you that this table has 6 `VARCHAR` columns, 2 timestamps, and 1 number. What you're looking for is something that is provided by most BI tools or data catalogs. I suggest you take a look at those instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot meta information in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

All the views and table functions in the Snowflake INFORMATION_SCHEMA can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're talking about viewing the information schema as mentioned, but if you need documentation on this whole new interface, it's called SnowSight
you can learn more there:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight.html

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The highlight in your screenshot isn't statistics about the data in the table, but merely about the query result (which looks like a `DESCRIBE TABLE` query). For example, if you look at `type`, it simply tells you that this table has 6 `VARCHAR` columns, 2 timestamps, and 1 number.

What you're looking for is something that is provided by most BI tools or data catalogs. I suggest you take a look at those instead.

You could also use an independent tool, like [Soda](https://www.soda.io/), which is open source.